# Finding the last transaction for each id

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
period<-c("calib","calib","calib","valid","valid","calib","calib","calib","valid")
date<-c("11-11-07","11-11-07","23-11-07","12-12-08","17-12-08","11-11-07","23-11-07","23-11-07","16-01-08")
time<-c(12,13,14,11,23,15,12,18,14)
df<-data.frame(id,period,time,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")


id period time     date      date2
 1  calib   12 11-11-07 2007-11-11
 1  calib   13 11-11-07 2007-11-11
 1  calib   14 23-11-07 2007-11-23
 1  valid   11 12-12-08 2008-12-12
 1  valid   23 17-12-08 2008-12-17
 3  calib   15 11-11-07 2007-11-11
 3  calib   12 23-11-07 2007-11-23
 3  calib   18 23-11-07 2007-11-23
 3  valid   14 16-01-08 2008-01-16
```

I need to extract the `date` of last transaction in the `calib` period, for each `id`, and put it in a new column. If two transactions have been made in one day (similar `date`) the last transaction should be chosen based on time of transaction.
The final table that I am looking for is as follows:

```
id period time     date      date2  last
 1  calib   12 11-11-07 2007-11-11   NA
 1  calib   13 11-11-07 2007-11-11   NA
 1  calib   14 23-11-07 2007-11-23 2007-11-23
 1  valid   11 12-12-08 2008-12-12   NA
 1  valid   23 17-12-08 2008-12-17   NA 
 3  calib   15 11-11-07 2007-11-11   NA
 3  calib   12 23-11-07 2007-11-23   NA
 3  calib   18 23-11-07 2007-11-23 2007-11-23
 3  valid   14 16-01-08 2008-01-16   NA
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how I might approach the problem with `rle`:

```
L1 <- lapply(split(df, df[, "id"]), function(dat){
    dat[, "last"] <- as.Date(NA)
    x <- rle(as.character(dat[, "period"]))
    z <- cumsum(x[["lengths"]])
    dat$last[z[x[["values"]] == "calib"]] <- dat[z[x[["values"]] == "calib"] , 
        "date2"]
    dat
})

data.frame(do.call(rbind, L1), row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: I noticed the removal of the checkmark as the correct answer.  Would you mind stating why this didn't meet your needs so I can re-tailor the response?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your comments here... in my actual data set it gives an error :Error in x$values : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: It has to do with your data set structure that differs from what you posted.  Indexing is safer than `$` so I made those changes.  In the future it would seem more sensible to add a comment stating something didn't work on your data so the person helping can make adjustments.  Everyone that sees this assumes my response is correct and so you'll never have your problem solved.

Comment: It was my fault as you said, I solved the problem with my data and your code is working perfectly. Many thanks!